# Как проверить на пустоту лист

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Как в стримах проверять на пустоту листа, если к примеру приходит пустой лист?
 Я скипаю все элементы кроме последнего. Но вот если придет пустой лист, выдает ошибку
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: -1

```
    int offset = updates.getResult()
            .stream()
            .skip(updates.getResult().size() - 1)
            .mapToInt(update -> update.getUpdateId() + 1)
            .findAny()
            .orElse(previousOffset);
```

Мну нужна информация из  последнего объекта в листе.

Comment: Никак, стримы не должны работать с состоянием. Что такое "последний ofset последнего объекта"?

Comment: сорри, не правильно сказал, просто нужна информация из последнего объекта в листе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно написать как-то так:

```java
List<Result> list = updates.getResult();
int offset = Stream.of(list.size() - 1)
    .filter(i -> i >= 0)
    .findFirst()
    .map(list::get)
    .map(Result::getUpdateId)
    .map(i -> i + 1)
    .orElse(previousOffset);
```

Только, как уже говорили, зачем? :)

Да и тогда уж проще использовать что-то такое (впрочем, тоже извращение):

```java
int offset = Optional.ofNullable(new LinkedList<>(updates.getResult()).pollLast())
    .map(Result::getUpdateId)
    .map(i -> i + 1)
    .orElse(previousOffset);
```

Answer (score 2):

А зачем тут вообще стрим?

```
List<SomeClass> list = updates.getResult();
SomeClass obj = list.isEmpty() ? null : list.get(list.size() - 1);
```

Comment: Да, так можно, так и проще, но мне хочется знать можно ли как то в моем примере сделать проверку внутри стримов

Comment: Если сильно постараться, то каким-нибудь грязным хаком этого наверняка можно добиться, но это потребует написания большего количества кода, в процессе работы будет требовать больше памяти, работать будет медленно и нестабильно. Вы пытаетесь применить инструмент не подходящий для этой задачи. [Почитайте.](https://habrahabr.ru/post/337350/)